# How to Convert DateTime to String in Django/DRF While Testing

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm testing an endpoint which naturally returns a JSON containing the datetime as a string.

I compare the response content in test as such:

```py
assert serializer_instance.data == {
    "created_at": str(model_instance.created_at),
    "updated_at": str(model_instance.updated_at),
}
```

`created_at` and `updated_at` are surely `DateTimeField`s. However, in this case, test fails saying:

```
E         Differing items:
E         {'created_at': '2020-06-24T12:42:03.578207+03:00'} != {'created_at': '2020-06-24 09:42:03.578207+00:00'}
E         {'updated_at': '2020-06-24T12:42:03.578231+03:00'} != {'updated_at': '2020-06-24 09:42:03.578231+00:00'}
```

So `str` uses a different formatting on datetimes. Sure, the test case can be passed successfully using `strftime`, but there should be an internal function that does it easily in either Django or Django Rest Framework and I'd like to learn it.

Thanks in advance.

---

## Environment

- Python 3.8.3
- Django 2.2.12
- Django Rest Framework 3.11.0

Answer (score 3):

I am a bit late to the party, But, better late than never!

I am using this method to assert datetime response in DRF

```
from rest_framework.fields import DateTimeField

drf_str_datetime = DateTimeField().to_representation
assert serializer_instance.data == {
    "created_at": drf_str_datetime(model_instance.created_at),
    "updated_at": drf_str_datetime(model_instance.updated_at),
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For DRF I normally use

```
obj.ts_updated.astimezone(timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE)).isoformat()
```

This matches the DRF format.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way. It uses [parse_datetime](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/utils/#django.utils.dateparse.parse_datetime) method and, instead of converting `DateTimeField` fields on model instance with `str`, I thought it's better both stay as `datetime`.

```py
from django.utils.dateparse import parse_datetime

data = serializer_instance.data
data["created_at"] = parse_datetime(data["created_at"])
# ... and the others ...

assert data == {
    # ... and the others ...
    "created_at": model_instance.created_at,
    # ... and the others ...
}
```

While this is okay, we mutate `serializer_instance.data` like this. I don't think it is going to be a problem in tests though.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
myDate.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

or

```
'{:%m/%d/%Y}'.format(myDate)
```

Comment: The datetime comes from DRF as string in format like `2020-06-24T12:42:03.578207+03:00`. Your `strftime` does not cover this format *and* an internal function in Django and DRF is preferred since they probably act accordingly to Django's settings.

Answer (score 0):

For **Django Rest Framework 3.11.0** you can use the following helper function to convert a Python datetime object into a string representation used by DRF:

```
from pytz import timezone as pytz_timezone

def convert_datetime_to_drf_str(date_time: datetime) -> str:
    return date_time.astimezone(pytz_timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE)).isoformat().replace("+00:00", "Z")
```

So, for your specific case it would be:

```
assert serializer_instance.data == {
    "created_at": convert_datetime_to_drf_str(model_instance.created_at),
    "updated_at": convert_datetime_to_drf_str(model_instance.updated_at),
}
```

or directly without the helper function:

```
from pytz import timezone as pytz_timezone

assert serializer_instance.data == {
    "created_at": model_instance.created_at.astimezone(pytz_timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE)).isoformat().replace("+00:00", "Z"),
    "updated_at": model_instance.updated_at.astimezone(pytz_timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE)).isoformat().replace("+00:00", "Z"),
}
```